# 3 special keys on Dell Inspiron 17R (5720)

Tags: 13.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, dell

I recently purchased a Dell Inspiron 17R (5720).

I wiped Windows 8 and installed Ubuntu 13.04 and everything is working well, except I have 3 buttons on the upper right corner of the keyboard that light when pressed, but don't register.

I tried `showkey -a` in a terminal window and they don't send a scancode or keycode.

I believe they are special like the power button, multimedia keys and lid switch.

Has any one found how to customize and/or use these three buttons?  Is there a utility to customize the Dell WMI hotkeys?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after searching for some time I found out that it is a bug that assigns incorrect keycodes to the these buttons (it assigned mine to super + x, keycode 224 (that's the next song multimedia button) and decrease brightness)
There currently is no way to fix this but the bug report has been filed and confirmed by multiple people.
Let's just hope they fix it for 13.05